# How to remove %20 and other special characters from a URL in NUXTJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working on my first serious javascript and nuxt project. I'm using Rest Countries API to create dynamic pages based on each country name. Like this:

```
<nuxt-link :to="/countries/ + country.name.toLowerCase()"><span>Learn more...</span></nuxt-link>
```

But for example, Åland Islands URL turns out like this: /countries/åland%20islands

I'd like to remove the %20 characters from the URL and perhaps other special characters. Where about and how on the nuxtjs application I can get it done?

I'd appreciate if you could give me some solutions.

Comment: https://cmty.app/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/c8619

Comment: mighty helpful: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/4977

Comment: why u want to remove it? its a valid url and thats how it should be .

Answer (score 1):

**have you tried decodeURIComponent() ?**

```
console.log(decodeURIComponent(country.name));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but,I suggest this method.In fact,%20 replaces the space in your link.I suggest that you should remove all the spaces in your link before routing to it:

As an example

```
<script>
   export default{
         methods:{

         VisitLink(name) {

              this.$router.push(name.trim().replace(/ /g, "- 
             ").toLowerCase());
},
         }
   }
</script>
```

I use the method trim() to make sure that there is not any space at the end of country name. Then,I remove the all the remaining space in NAME.
But,if you still want to use nuxtJs link you can create a method like

```
<script>
 export default{
   methods:{
    getLink(name){
       return  name.trim().replace(/ /g, "- 
             ").toLowerCase()
     }
    }
  }
</script>
```

and then

```
<nuxt-link :to="getLink(country.name)"><span>Learn more...</span></nuxt-link>
```

I hope,it could help someone